# Flex box's child box do not have 100% Height

Tags: css, flexbox

CSS, Flexbox have a height problem.
Child box do not have a 100% height.
What is the problem with this?

```
<div class="flex">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

[CSS]

```
.flex{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  height:100%;
}

.item{
  flex: 1;
}
```

Item box have just content's height.
I'd like to expand height of child box,
so I put this code into the flex css.

```
align-items:stretch;
align-content:stretch;
```

Nothing happened.

Please give me an advice for me.

Comment: Is the `.flex` div a child as well or just in the `body`?

Comment: Yeah every object's located in the body. I put the specific code in CSS such as html,body{height:100%;} also

Comment: I made a quick jsfiddle and appears to be fine in Chrome and Firefox? - https://jsfiddle.net/Lc88fmd8/ - What browser/ device are you using?

Comment: @Richard do you have content inside of the divs? Like text or images?